# how do I plot data on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and I'm trying to understand how matplotlib works. I've got data for gamestop stocks and was trying to map volume over time and I followed what the book said to do when plotting data but my code isn't working. Can you tell me what I did wrong?
Someone down below answered my question. The issue was that I had more values in y than I had in x. Thanks for everyones help.
here's my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10022500, 4961500, 6056200, 6129300, 6482000, 37382200, 78183100, 42698500, 62427300, 81345000, 25687300, 26843100]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('volume')
plt.ylabel('day')
plt.title('volume over time')
plt.show()
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_34116/3774317828.py in <module>
      1 x = [10022500, 4961500, 6056200, 6129300, 6482000, 37382200, 78183100, 42698500, 62427300, 81345000, 25687300, 26843100]
      2 y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
----> 3 plt.plot(x,y)
      4 plt.xlabel('volume')
      5 plt.ylabel('day')

D:\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   3017 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   3018 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 3019     return gca().plot(
   3020         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   3021         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

D:\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1603         """
   1604         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1605         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1606         for line in lines:
   1607             self.add_line(line)

D:\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    313                 this += args[0],
    314                 args = args[1:]
--> 315             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    316 
    317     def get_next_color(self):

D:\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    499 
    500         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 501             raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    502                              f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    503         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (12,) and (14,)
```

Comment: Could you show us what kind of error you're getting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging help, you need to provide the expected output and actual output (or if you get an error, the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)). For reference, see [mre]. For more tips, see [ask]. You can add images with Ctrl+G or by clicking the picture icon; for more info, see the [Markdown help](/editing-help#images).

Comment: I'll provide the errors when I get home I had to run to the grocery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Y dimensions are wrong. You have 12 elements for X and 14 elements for Y. What happens when matplot steps to (?,13) and (?,14)? The following code works and produces the given image:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [10022500, 4961500, 6056200, 6129300, 6482000, 37382200, 
     78183100, 42698500, 62427300, 81345000, 25687300, 26843100]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('volume')
plt.ylabel('day')
plt.title('volume over time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: quick comment, I think time should always be on the x-axis

Comment: I agree. If I were to optimize this I'd probably do `plt.plot(range(len(x)),x)` just so that I don't have to deal with mismatches like this